# CS- cart custom form and ajax response

Tags: cs-cart

Actually I am new in cs-cart and I am trying to show my result set into html/smarty block which contains the form code which I added from backend

Design->Layout but it only shows response in console ,I am pasting of some code here

Block code (added from backend Design->Layouts) :

```
<div class="quick-quote">
<h3>Quick Quote!</h3>
<form class="cm-ajax" action="index.php" method="post" id="quick_quote_form"> 
<div id="quick-quote">
<div class="clearfix">
<label style="width:73px;" >Width:</label>
</div>

<div class="input">
<input type="text" placeholder="enter width" name="d_width" id="d_width" class="required form-control" >
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
<label style="width:73px;" >Height:</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="get-quote-btn" value="Get Quote" name="dispatch[get_qoute.get_rates]" /> 
 </div>
 <div class="result"></div>
 <!-- tag -->
 <input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="result" />
 </form>
 </div>
 Controller code:
   <?php
  use Tygh\Registry;
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if ($mode == 'get_rates') {
  $height= $_POST["d_height"];
  $width=$_POST["d_width"];
  $val = $height+$width;
  Registry::get('view'); 
  Registry::get('ajax')->assign('get_rates', $val);
 } 
 exit;
 }
 ?>
  Result set is coming correctly , Now I don't know how to show response in block div.
 <div class="result"></div>
 <!-- tag -->
 <input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="result" />
  Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont goto design ->layout because its common for all forms and pages.
Goto the website menu-> content then choose the form you want to change, there you can see layout tab, edit block done.

Answer (score 0):

In form you set what block must refresh by ajax method

```
<input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="result" />
```

Your problem in this line:

```
 <div class="result"></div>
```

> All refresh results must be in ID tag:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```